# iOS - schedule multiple local notifications, UNCalendarNotificationTrigger

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I want to develop a reminder app that need to send local notification when we set the reminder. I developed some code that triggers only one notification even i set multiple notifications. if i set reminders at 7:30 PM, 7:31 PM, 7:32 PM, the notification is showing only at 7:32PM.

Here is my code

```
    func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Reminder"
    content.body = "To day is the last date for the payment of your card. Please make payment today."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.categoryIdentifier = "PaymentReminderIdentifier"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "ReminderNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

//

```
func notif() {
    let selectedDate = fullDate
    print("Selected date: \(selectedDate)")
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    delegate?.scheduleNotification(at: selectedDate!)
}
```

i want to deliver notifications every time when i create the reminder. 
help me to resolve this problem. thank you...

Answer (score 4):

use different identifier in each time. it will work